# Windows Update KB3023266 repeated installation

Tags: windows, update

Windows Update KB3023266 is installed on every shutdown of the computer. On next start, the update log shows an additional entry like this:

Name: Vulnerability in Windows Application Compatibility cache could allow elevation of privilege: January 13, 2015 (KB3023266)
Date: ‎27.‎01.‎2015 13:45
Status: Successful
Type: Important

But it is still possible to install it manually and the same update will install automatically again and again and again on every shutdown, restart.

I tried WindowsUpdateDiagnostic and MicrosoftFixit with no success.

How should I fix it. Manually resetting the whole windows update is a long and tedious thing to do(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058). Would it even fix this problem?

*edit*
I tried to install it manually (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45454). It completed with success but the problem persists, see my comment to Overminds answer.
*edit*

Comment: I had same problem. I tried to install this update manually. I noticed that this update is only for windows 32-bit 7. Pls try this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45461.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread at the microsoft help forums provides a solution and also exhaustively lists all procedures that did NOT qualify as a solution in this special case:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-repeatedly-offers-the-same-update/38a732dc-c0de-4d9d-84b7-36135b3d5d5d

tl;dr

If everything else fails, fall back to an in place upgrade repair:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2255099

Answer (score 0):

Get the update from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45455
Manually install it.
It just installs, nothing complex is required.

Comment: I tried that. It installs successfully and one more entry about successful installation is added to the Update History. One reboot later it still asks to install the same update again and on shutdown it automatically installs the update again (creating one more restore point as well).

Comment: Did you try unistalling the failed ones first ? Open Installed Updates by going to Programs and Features, clicking View installed updates.
Select the update that you want to remove, and then click Uninstall. Reboot. Then try to install the clean one from the lone package.If that wont work, more investigations will be needed. A solution would be to identify all files that update (you can do that by looking at the temporary ones when the package is extracting) and where windows puts them, so you can completely manually clean-up the initial update, but this may vary in complexity a lot.

Comment: This one is not listed with the installed updates.